# How to hide macro code from a user using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**I already know how to hide macro code from the user**; Simply open up your VBA project and go `Tools` - `VBAProject Properties` - `Protection` and check `Lock project for viewing` enter a password and your code is made inaccessible to users.

I want to know if this can be automated with VBA.

*Why?*

I have a sheet of data that I use a macro to scramble, and a key to unscramble. A macro runs on a `Workbook_open` event and I want to guarantee this runs *before* the user can access any content.

When a user opens the workbook, they can just hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> or choose not to enable macros, I don't want that. So I hide the macro code and protect all the cells **by default** using a really long and strong password. Part of the `Workbook_open` code then removes these restrictions (presumably by using the password), and of course the `Workbook_open` code only runs if macros are enabled.

So can I toggle the viewing status with VBA? I imagine some string of `SendKeys` would do the job, but not ideal.

Comment: There is literally nothing you can do to protect an Excel file in this manner from a *deliberate* attempt to hack it by a reasonably-knowledgeable user. The best you can do is safeguard against accidental stuff and n00b users. Heck, the user can disable macros via Security setting. There is no VBA you can use that will circumvent or override *that*.

Comment: You do know that is is fairly common knowledge to break a workbook's vba project passwrd..?

Comment: I would lock the VBproject and Workbook structure, and make the protected sheet `xlVeryHidden`, and have your `Open` event unprotect and make it `xlVisible`. That's the best you can do. In that case if the macros are disabled, the user won't be able to do anything until/unless she hacks your VBProject, and if she's that competent, there's nothing you can do anyways.

Comment: There's not much you can do to protect an Excel file in this manner from an ***accidental*** non-attempt not to hack it by a completely unknowledgeable user. What do you do when macro security is set too high by policy (or the user) to allow it to run?

Comment: @Jeeped and in response to David Zemen's first comment; Perhaps I made my intent unclear. I'm aware that Excel security is weak. I wanted to employ this technique as a trigger to mid-level users that macros must be enabled. Without too much detail it's for a challenge, no hacking allowed, just inventive uses of Excel to force the situation on someone, and their task is to look at macros and formulae and unravel the sheet's workings. I don't want to override security settings - I thought I made that clear in the question, the user *decides* to turn on macros, otherwise the workbook is unusable.

Comment: @Comintern Similar to above, high macro security is precisely the situation I want to deal with. By making the sheet *and* code inaccessible (in an Excel clean fashion, not in an inaccessible to hackers fashion), and by leaving some explanatory note, I prompt users to lower their macro security, allowing the event to run. So I'm not *really* looking for a workaround what you describe. Of course if a user is un-knowledgeable enough not to have the admin privileges, then sure, I'm stuck.

Comment: @DavidZemens - with regard to your second comment, I agree that that would protect the workbook from all non-hacking users, forcing the macro-enable that I'm after. In fact I intend to use `xlVeryHidden`. However it doesn't really solve my problem, as I want the code accessible once the macro has run (or after a series of predetermined events), automatically and without having to give the users a password. Perhaps in this case the *why* isn't important, maybe I shouldn't have included it in my question, really I just want to know whether I can toggle the viewing status automatically.

Comment: you can't toggle it unless macros are enabled, and even then I am not 100% sure you can lock/unlock the VBProject using vba.. if you can, it would require user allows programmatic access to vba project object model, and this has to be done manually by the user as it's explicitly impossible to use VBA, even with SendKeys, to toggle the macro security or anything else in Trust Center settings.

Answer (score 0):

What about having two spreadsheet?
One of them will be for the user, you save it as Excel Workbook only (not Excel Macro-Enable Workbook). So the user won't even be able to see that there is a macro associated to it.
The other spreadsheet will be only for you, which you will import all the data the user adds to the other spreadsheet automatically and you can access the macro when you need it.

Comment: Actually, I'm happy for the user to view/edit the macro code, provided I've run the first macro.

Comment: Your main question is: "How to hide macro code from a user using VBA", but now you say you are ok with the user viewing and editing the macro code.

I am not sure now what you are looking for.
Am I correct: You want to start the macro not accessible for the user, once the macro runs what it needs to run, you want it become accessible again?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The macro code must be hidden *and* un-hidden programatically, so that the user can access it only once the first macro has run.

Comment: Well, I would assume no macro can change the VBA settings as you mentioned before, but I think there are ways to work it out.

First, it is possible to make the macro run without the user needing to press any button for it to happen: [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Run-a-macro-5535c4ee-ff91-4e99-9704-99a49f1dcdf4#__toc270927005).
Now if there is buttons in your spreadsheet, instead of linking the button with the macro, make the macro link the button for you. `    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Macro1"`.

Comment: So, whenever the macro finishes its rotine, you attribute the button(s) with their respective macro(s) and you are good to go!

Comment: ps: The other macros should not run while one of them is working, but just in case, make sure to disable the buttons when you initialize your worksheet before the routine.